How to approximate the time-dependent Hamiltonian in quantum adiabatic theory by the non time-dependent Hamiltonian?
Recently, I am learning how to solve the linear equation $A\left | x  \right \rangle =\left | b  \right \rangle $ using quantum adiabatic theory. In the solving process, people usually need to set the initial Hamiltonian $H_0:=\begin{pmatrix}0&Q_b\\Q_b&0\end{pmatrix}$
and the final Hamiltonian $H_1:=\begin{pmatrix}0&AQ_b\\Q_bA&0\end{pmatrix}$. Where $Q_{b}=I_{N}-|b\rangle \langle b|$. Then evolve through the Hamiltonian $H(s)=(1-f(s))H_0+f(s)H_1$ Where $f(s):[0,1]\to[0,1]$. Consider the situation of vanilla AQC here. That is, $f(s)=s$. Now I have a problem, I don't know how to simulate the time-dependent Hamiltonian $H(s)$ through a circuit. I don't know why the ground state of the evolved state is the solution to a system of linear equations.
If someone could help me answer this question and provide a code (if possible), I would greatly appreciate it.
